# Как отладить EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, разработка-игр, отладка, spritekit

Мое приложение ( игра - Swift + SpriteKit) в случайный момент времени вылетает с EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Использую Singleton, один контроллер. Товарищи экстрасенсы, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вылет обычно происходит при переключении между меню. (каждая меню в отдельной сцене). Во время самого игрового процесса вылетаний не заметил. При это приложение не убивается со всем, при двойном нажатии кнопки home его можно "вернуть" обратно.(при этом, как я понял, пересоздается контроллер)

Comment: давайте больше информации. указывает ли оно на какую то память (например 0x34545), включите symbolic, exception и swift error breakpoint, может что то обнаружится

Comment: еще backtrace на момент крэша, и если получится через брейкпоинты идентифицировать строку или состояние на момент вылета